# Where can I find suitable replacements for Cap Gasket on Zurn Wilkins 600XL 1" Pressure Regulator

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, seal

While I was working on rebuilding my Zurn Wilkins 600XL 1" Water Pressure Regulator Valve I broke x3 of the x4 sets of Cap Gasket seals that I had (don't ask me the sequence of events that led to me posessing x4 sets of Cap Gaskets...)
[image]
[image]

They seem to be some kind of cardboard material, and apparently they are 'one time use'.

Once you tighten the cap, and they get moist, and make seal up with the brass body, they break if you loosen the caps again.
[image]

I called Zurn Wilkins, but they don't sell those seals individually, only in the rebuild kits that cost $50 which I had already bought.  I didn't want to buy a whole other kit just for those seals.

So I went searching to various hardware stores for suitable alternatives.

One promising option that I found was a sheet of blank rubber seal material that I could cut out to appropriate diameters
[image]

but that turned out to not be a solution.
[image]

Does anyone know where I can find replacement cap gaskets for the Zurn Wilkins 600XL 1" Pressure Regulator?

Comment: While questions asked with the intent of self-answering are 100% acceptable and are often quite useful (this certainly should be to anyone in the same boat), they need to _actually ask a question_. Please edit to put a question in the title and ask an actual question in the body. Once you do that, this will be excellent and I'm sure will help people out!

Comment: @FreeMan Sure thing.  Sorry about that, didn't know.  Just edited.

Comment: Unfortunately, "where can I buy" is a shopping question that risks being closed as off topic! _Sorry, you can't win for loosing here :D_ Something along the lines of "what would work as a replacement gasket for... since they're only available in a rebuild kit" would be, IMO, a great way of asking. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan - edited

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, on my last attempt of the day, I found a landscaping shop that I was just drivng by, and planned to ignore, but at the last moment I decided to give it a try, and pulled into the parking lot.  The guy there was familiar with the seal material and where I could buy some blank sheets.

Turns out that material is called Rubber Cellulose used to seal water and coolant applications, and can be bought at automotive part stores in blank sheets.
[image]
[image]

I got some at O'Reilly's, but the guy said they have them at Napa, and probably other auto shops too.

I cut out a couple sets of seals, and they are working like a charm.
[image]
[image]